# Interstitial Topics

Tags: word-choice

I'm in the process of writing course descriptions and syllabi. I desire to list select topics that don't require deep focus as in one unit of a course, but they are significant in the sense that they will be scattered throughout.

I have chosen a heading for this section called "Interstitial Topics" and I like this choice of words as it reflects the idea that I'll be scattering some extra knowledge "in small places" as per the definition of interstitial.

However, are interstices more of a physical space? I googled "interstices" and see an example "sunshine filtered through the interstices of the arching trees" which is more physical than abstract.

Is my use of the word odd or appropriate in this case?

Comment: I think the answer is *both*.  It is slightly odd to use it this way, but also conveys your meaning well and develops interest in the possible meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word [interstitial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstitial) does refer to a physical space, though that is also true for *deep* focus, which you use in your question without hesitation. *Supporting* topics would have a similar physical link.

Using a physical concept in an abstract way is well established. For example, the previous link turned up [interstitial art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstitial_art) (artwork that is difficult to categorise), which is an abstract usage of the word.

Unless your primary topic is architecture, *Interstitial Topics* conveys the idea of interesting topics that don't quite fit into the main topics.